# Can aws t3.small run a socket with 2000 concurrent users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2

We are servicing apps with 600 to 2000 concurrent users.
Currently, it only connects to the `socket` when using the function, so the number of connections to the actual `socket` is much less than the number of concurrent users.

but

I would like to add a function that displays the currently connected user. So, we plan to keep all connectors connected to the `socket`. In this case, is it okay to service to t3.small right now?

Currently, there are not many socket-related functions, so it costs about $20 per month.

If 2000 people connect to the socket and maintain the connection, is it possible with the specification now? If possible, will there be a lot of extra charges?

Comment: The only way to truly know is to create a test-bed that can simulate that number of users doing whatever they normally do with your application. Then monitor how the instance is performing.

Answer (score 0):

> we plan to keep all connectors connected to the socket. In this case, is it okay to service to t3.small right now?

It depend on how heavy is your traffic and socket. If you want to make sure, do a test and watch the metric of your instances to make sure it can or not

> If 2000 people connect to the socket and maintain the connection, is it possible with the specification now? If possible, will there be a lot of extra charges?

Yes, AWS charge for in and out network traffic **to the Internet**

edit: add the Bold text

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Thanks